# Analyse de « des » dans un poème de Laforgue

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, littérature, france

Dans un passage de *Petites Misères de Juillet* (1881-1886), de Jules Laforgue, le mot « des » pose un problème ; on s'attend à « les yeux » ou « aux yeux » au lieu de « des yeux ».

> Vois, la Lune même (cette amie)
> Salive et larmoie en opulente ophtalmie…
>
> Et voici que des bleus sous-bois ont miaulé
> Les mille nymphes ! et (qu'est-ce que vous voulez)
> Aussitôt mille touristes des yeux las rôdent,
> Tremblants, mais le cœur harnaché d'âpres méthodes !

Comment l'analyser ?

Comment: ***Des** yeux* =  ***d***'indéfinissables, ***de*** nombreuses paires ***d***'yeux ***de*** toutes natures, ***d***'invisibles *yeux* … rôdent

Comment: @Personne Une apposition alors ? Intéressant, mais sans une virgule ?

Comment: *Apposition* ne fait pas partie de mon vocabulaire, mais, mettre une virgule entre le sujet et le verbe ne fait pas partie non plus de mon apprentissage.

Comment: @Personne On ne se comprend pas : « Aussitôt mille touristes, des yeux las, rôdent ».

Comment: La grammaire s'arrête au doigt du poète qui montre la Lune… comprenne qui pourra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je l'entends comme synonyme d'*avec*, locution adverbiale jointe au verbe *rôdent* plutôt qu'au nom *touristes*.

Ils rôdent avec leurs yeux qui sont las, tout comme on regarde d'un œil indiscret, écoute d'une oreille distraite, danse d'un pied sur l'autre, etc.

Certainement on peut souvent utiliser *à* à la place, p.ex. j'ai vu des articles sur des jeux auxquels on joue *d'une* ou *à une* seule main. Je ne saurais analyser la grammaire derrière le choix mais l'interprétation m'en semble assez claire.

Comment: Justement, c'est dans le cas d'un « les » ou d'un « aux » que l'interprétation « avec » est immédiate, et dans ces cas la grammaire est claire (encore qu'une virgule serait nécessaire pour « les »), mais que dire de la grammaire de ce « des » ?

Comment: « des » serait donc « de les » où « de » est la préposition ; ça me semble la seule approche grammaticale. Il ne reste plus qu'à cerner la nuance dans ce « de », qui est encore, à peu près synonyme de « avec ».